# Tela flutuante Cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação com o Cordova, e preciso exibir algumas informações trazidos do BD quando o usuário clicar em um botão, porem não posso enviar para outra tela, gostaria de exibir uma espécie de popup, existe como fazer isto?
Obs.: Já tentei utilizar Toast porém não é o que preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Ja que você esta utilizando JqueryMobile com o Phonegap, o que você precisa é de um Dialog.

```
<a href="dialog.html" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Open dialog</a>
```

Leia mais na documentação do Jquery e veja exemplo aqui [Dialog Jquery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/pages-dialog/)

[image: Dialog Jquery Mobile]